# Has anyone seen this error, "Start-ScheduledTask : Invalid class" when trying to use powershell to start a scheduled task?

Tags: powershell

First, let me say that I have this command working on 10 different servers with no problem at all.
The 11th server however is the one giving me the issue and I can't figure out why.

I am running this command: powershell Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Selenium Nodes'
Below you can see the error I am getting.
Yes, that scheduled task works on its own.
Yes, I have deleted the scheduled task and recreated it.
Yes, that scheduled task is spelled correctly.
I tested on other machines the error is very different if any of the above were issues.
This is never even getting that far.

```
C:\Users\jenkins>powershell Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Selenium Nodes'
Start-ScheduledTask : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Selenium Nodes'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Start-ScheduledTask
   ], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Start-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious - but I'm really puzzled by the combination of using Command Line to launch Powershell to start a Scheduled Task. Why exactly do you do it this way? Surely you could start it directly from Powershell or Command Line without needing to use both, which would make your problem simpler to troubleshoot, if it still happens at all.

Comment: @SteveTaylor thanks for the reply.
On my windows system, there is a Task that is already to run during startup.
This part works fine.  This task ensures that my selenium node is always running after a reboot.
There are times that I need to push a patch.  So I have a Jenkins job that stops selenium updates it and then calls Start-ScheduledTask which in turn starts up all my required selenium nodes windows.  I do this rather than just reboot the server.
So I am not on the system myself to do this but using automation.

Comment: Right, your use case is a bit clearer now, thanks. But why use `CMD > Powershell > Scheduled Task`, rather than `CMD > Scheduled Task`, or using the Jenkins job to launch `Powershell > Scheduled Task`? (I haven't used Jenkins personally, but from a quick search that seems to be within its capabilities)

Comment: @SteveTaylor
There is a batch file on each system that looks like this.
`powershell curl -Method GET -Uri https://artifactory.com/artifactory/my.zip -OutFile C:\my.zip -H @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api' = XXX'} -UseBasicParsing"
 powershell expand-archive -path C:\my.zip -destinationpath C:\
 powershell Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Selenium Nodes'`

The main reason I have run this scheduled task is the scheduled task is named the same on all systems, I have 11 of them.
What that scheduled task calls could be slightly different on each on each system.

Comment: @SteveTaylor
It is only the last powershell command on the one system that gives me the trouble. :-)
I might have some other workarounds and actually, just was not ready to give up just yet. :-)

Comment: so would it be fair to say that using command line / bat file is actually an unnecessary step, and it could be done with a .ps1 file on each system instead, which Jenkins could run? Do you get the same error when you log into the 11th server, open Powershell directly and then run `Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Selenium Nodes'`?

Comment: Also worth checking if the `ScheduledTasks` module is actually installed on that 11th server, though I'd have expected a different error message.

Comment: @SteveTaylor
Thank you, yes, if I run the command directly in PowerShell I get the same error.
I will try moving it to the ps1 files and try again.  I suspect I will see the same.
I will also double-check the module is installed.
Thanks for the help.  I only posted and asked in the hope that it was something obvious to someone who uses powershell often but most likely it is something with just my server.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to rebuild the WMI Repository
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/21413-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository

1. sc config winmgmt start= disabled
2. net stop winmgmt
3. Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
   Winmgmt /resetrepository %
4. windir%\System32\wbem
5. sc config winmgmt start= auto